# Why MKTileOverlay repeats same tile over and over for openstreet map in ios, swift4

Tags: ios, mapkit, swift4, openstreetmap, mktileoverlay

I'm using OpenStreet map to with our own map server with iOS. for iOS I couldn't find any third party library (free or paid) which can use with our open StreetMap server. then I decided to go with MKMapView using MKTileOverlay like below :

added a MapKit outlet to my storyboard. made a outlet connection and set delegates to self using storyboard and then here is my viewdidload method.

```
let urltemplate = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/17/94621/62995.png"
let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: urltemplate)
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
mapView.add(overlay)
```

then the output is like below :

[image: Out put of Map]

Any idea of what is going on. when I scroll to right of left I can only see this image. please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's exactly what you specified in your URL template.

Instead of

`http://tile.openstreetmap.org/17/94621/62995.png`

use

`http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

Comment: then How can I pass thos z, x and y values

Comment: MKTileOverlay is supposed to fill them automatically. It should support the XYZ tile scheme. Z refers to the zoom level while X and Y are coordinates. See [slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) for details.